# function for finding non-identical elements in two vectors

Tags: r, vector

Simple question, but didn't find it on stackoverflow. Is there a function for finding all non-identical values:

```
x <- c("a","b","c","d")
y <- c("a","f","g","c","d")
```

result should be:

```
res <- c("b","f","g")
```

All functions seem to only work for one vector. `setdiff()` etc.

Comment: Keyword: *symmetric difference*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This popped up on [Tony Breyal's blog](http://tonybreyal.wordpress.com/2011/11/29/outersect-the-opposite-of-rs-intersect-function/) a few years ago, you can see several solutions there, here's the shortest one:

```
c(setdiff(x,y),setdiff(y,x))
```

Comment: thanks, I thought of this one too, but expected that there's a function which directly handles this problem.

Comment: You could use Tony's `outersect` function if you need to do this a lot in a session, or bundle it into a script of your own. BTW, you should show that your question has been answered by clicking on the check below the up/down arrows.

Answer (score 4):

```
setdiff(union(x, y), intersect(x, y))
```

Answer (score 1):

Longhand form:

```
c(x[!x %in% y],y[!y %in% x])
#[1] "b" "f" "g"
```